# Cadence PCB designer How to extract the ground plane shape

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, ground-plane, dxf

how to extract the shape of the ground plane metal (only the gnd net) in dxf format from cadence PCB Designer?
Note that the ground plane is a autogenerated dynamic shape so if I move it I lose the shape of traces, vias and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Save the .brd file to a new name. Change the shape type to static. Then z-copy it to a newly created etch layer and display only what you want to be exported into the DXF file.